# On web scraping best practices

Tags: java, python, language-agnostic, web-scraping

Given:

**Client side**

1 - a database

2 - a coding language

**Server side:**

1 - a website that is displaying its own database results (a chronologically descending list of blog posts let's say, that can change if the site/author updates a post) with each post having a unique ID that does not change.

By and large does anyone have any good resources that helped them understand how to best approach this problem?

Computationally this type of work is time consuming just due to the nature of crawling a website and waiting for results (for me, at least).

My typical process (pseudo):

```
for each page on url:
  for each post on page:
      id = getID(post)
      data1...dataN = getData(post)
      call sql.execute("insert ... on duplicate key update")
```

The sql part is tedious and not efficient, and I feel there must be a better way to accomplish what I am doing in this flow.

The overall goal is always:

1 - grab data i care about from site (acknowledging here CSS/site can change where on average I am using xpath to find data) and stop when I have gotten to point where I already captured this data (Meaning: I am at a post ID already in my database assuming posts are always in descending order, and ID do not change).

2 - feed data through later analysis in some language best fit for the type of problem I am trying to solve.

On average (and this doesn't matter but) the packages I use here are:
beautiful soup, selenium, mechanize etc.

Comment: You should check out Beautiful Soup http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

Comment: @JeffC yes I reference beautiful soup in my post.